# what is best method to document your .Net code?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, editor

You and me both know that creating a document for codes is really boring and i opened this as a discussion that you share your experience for creating document for your code.

i think project documentation is differs from code documentation in a project documentation you can use UML to describe the whole projects,algorithms,designs, architecture.However your code documentation is very effective while your developing a DLL library or providing a web service or any other codes that will be use from other developers.
i think discussion subjects is :

### 1.Tools that you know useful for generating documentation

### 2.Methods and Rules for providing a source documentation

### 3.Does other developer code comment helped you what was useful

Comment: I don't really want to be `that` guy, but this may get down-voted because it's a discussion and not a specific question.

Comment: some other tools which is imported to vs for that just reopen it to provide you a good answer

Comment: http://www.helixoft.com/vsdocman/overview.html

Comment: your qestion is very simple!!

Comment: just have a look at link which provided in previous comment and then write comment first of all check whole page then release words

Comment: @Fresheteh it's not a question it's a discussion for sharing your experiences for document your code i am sure you have never had experienced other corporations outsource projects

Answer (score 1):

This is one of those things that the community in general tends to disagree on.  Not in general... I think we all acknowledge that code documentation is A Good Thing™, but *how* we do it is a personal matter.

Here is my take on it:

---

I know it's painful, but inline documentation helps to keep you focused, as well as giving you some information you can refer to when you look back at the code.

1) I use [Sandcastle](http://sandcastle.codeplex.com/) to generate help files from my libraries, which I document with XML document comments.

2a) Always provide reasonable XML documentation for your public fields, properties and methods.  *Don't* just put `/// <summary>FieldName</summary>`, describe what the field is for.

2b) Use inline comments sparingly.  Don't comment every line, but do comment blocks of code that do something interesting or in an interesting way, just so you (or anyone else) can understand it clearly next time you read the code.

3) Abso-freaking-lutely.  Reading my own code is usually pretty simple, but every developer works differently.  When you have a piece of code somebody else wrote, comments can make the difference between understanding and not.